# How to count the output of a conditional statement?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to count the number of posts on my wordpress site that have a timestamp that is greater than or equal to today.

I've put the current time and the post timestamp into two variables and guess it would begin:

```
if ($timestamp >= $curent_time) {
```

And also include `count` and perhaps `the_post()`

But I'm stuck. I can't figure it out how to put it together. Any ideas?

Comment: Loop through list of posts running the above condition and when condition is met increment a counter variable, After loop is done that variable will be equal to the number of posts that met the condition. You should be able to just do this as a SQL query where the above can be done easily where it will return the count without needing to loop.

Comment: what `count` and `the_post()` are? The last one should be a function, that you have defined? Why don't you try to extract from database and assign variables for the counted value, then go it through the IF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do some kind of loop with your posts and then increase the counter inside the condition, something like:

```
$curent_time = date('d-m-Y'); //or whatever format date

$cont = 0;

//for each post
foreach($posts as $post){
    $timestamp = $post['timestamp'] // or whatever

    if ($timestamp >= $curent_time) {
        $cont++;
    }
}

echo $cont;
```

Comment: I think you need to use `$timestamp = strtotime($post["timestamp"]);` to be able to compare it.

Comment: @user1444027 you can accept the answer if that's what you wanted. :)